# Checking if a line intersects a circle with SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to write a function in JS that given an SVG line and circle, will determine if that line intersects that circle. However, I think I'm having issues due to the SVG coordinate system. The function I've written is as follows:

```js
var inCircle = function(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, r) {

  // put circle at the center to simplify calcs
  ax -= cx; ay -= cy;
  bx -= cx; by -= cy;

  a = ax^2 + ay^2 - r^2;
  b = 2*(ax*(bx - ax) + ay*(by - ay));
  c = (bx - ax)^2 + (by - ay)^2;

  // get discriminant
  disc = b^2 - 4*a*c;

  // check if discriminant has real values
  if(disc <= 0) return false;

  // find intersection points
  sqrtdisc = Math.sqrt(disc);
  t1 = (-b + sqrtdisc)/(2*a);
  t2 = (-b - sqrtdisc)/(2*a);
  if(0 < t1 && t1 < 1 && 0 < t2 && t2 < 1) return true;
  return false;
};
```

I'm using the method outlined in this [stackexchange comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/275537), but not getting any results. Anyone have insight as to why this method wouldn't work? Thanks!

Comment: Forget you have this code. Then pretend it's a math problem and solve it on a piece of paper manually. Finally convert your solution into code.

Comment: The [intersection library](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/) can help with that.

Comment: thanks @LarsKotthoff, I tried using the method in that library and it checked out. Now to go back through my math and see where the mistake was...

Comment: In JavaScript, `r^2` doesn't give r squared Try `Math.pow(r, 2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you have interpreted the quadratic equation in the reverse order. Try this instead:

```
c = ax^2 + ay^2 - r^2;
b = 2*(ax*(bx - ax) + ay*(by - ay));
a = (bx - ax)^2 + (by - ay)^2;
```

and then continue with the other calculations using these definitions.